# Stuck with Power Automate basics

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow I am trying to complete but I just cant seem to get my head around it , I designed a flow for the following task:

Create a Power Automate flow named Sales Flow that meets the following requirements:

Sales Flow must run every weekday at 08:00 AM. The flow must evaluate the TestExcel.xlsx file that is located in sharepoint page.

The flow must only share opportunities that have a "Status" in the "Status" Column of "New" to an email of xxxxxxxx@gmail.com. The subject of the email must be Daily Opportunities.

The results must be formatted by using a table.

After I finish it I get the following result in the mail:

@odata.etag ItemInternalId  Opportunities Daily Customer    Status  Amount
2283f5af-822c-4b4a-85c9-716c334e5e69    App in a Day workshop   1   New 1000
32715c6a-4d82-4492-9a7a-8960a206fe47    Implement Power Platform Center Of Excellence   3   New 5000
b4c55401-e3f5-46bd-bac1-a5b8fb876ad2    App in a Day workshop   5   New 4000

I dont want to receive the @odata.etag  ItemInternalId that dont exist in the excel file
and when I try the Select Action or edit HTML table actions I just cancel out the filter or get all the results, help please anyone!

[image]